# Button for sending email with vba code

Tags: vba, forms, email, ms-access, button

I have created a button on my Access 2010 form. I want to send an email to all my customers in my Table and add a report to email. Also my report is customer based therefore i had to create report by using form. I couldnt manage to get a customer based report without form.

I managed to most of the project. However, when i say go to next record on form and change the information my code doesnot work. acNext is not doing its job. Is there a way to make it work?

Comments and variables are on my main language if you dont mind.

Thanks

```
Public Sub Komut15_Click()


    Dim oApp As New Outlook.Application
    Dim oemail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim fileName As String, todaydate As String


    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.Openrecordset("SELECT Ad, Soyad, Email, Limit, Adres FROM Musteriler Sorgu")

    Do Until rs.EOF

    On Error Resume Next
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNext



        'Raporu müşteri bazında olması için düzenliyoruz

         DoCmd.OpenReport "MusteriRaporu", acViewReport, "", "[Forms]![MusteriFormu]![Ad]=[Musteriler]![Ad]", acNormal


        'Raporu pdf file olarak dışa aktarıyoruz
        todaydate = Format(Date, "DDMMYYYY")
        fileName = Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\MusteriRaporu_" & todaydate & ".pdf"
        DoCmd.OutputTo acReport, "MusteriRaporu", acFormatPDF, fileName, False



        Set oemail = oApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        oemail.To = rs.Fields("Email")
        oemail.Subject = Me.Firma_Adı & " Bakiye Raporu"
        oemail.Body = "Bakiye raporunuz ektedir."
        oemail.Attachments.Add fileName


        With oemail
            If Not oemail.To <> Me.Email Then
                .Send
                MsgBox "Email Gonderildi"

            Else
                MsgBox "Mail adresi hatalı!"

            End If

        End With
     rs.MoveNext

    On Error Resume Next
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNext

    Loop


    rs.Close

    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing



End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Looping through Recordset:

```
Public Sub Komut15_Click()
    On Error GoTo ErrProc

    Dim oApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim oemail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim fileName As String, todaydate As String

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    Set oApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT Ad, Soyad, Email, Limit, Adres FROM Musteriler Sorgu")

    If rs.EOF Then GoTo Leave
    rs.MoveLast
    rs.MoveFirst

    Dim idx As Integer
    For idx = 1 To rs.RecordCount

        'Raporu müsteri bazinda olmasi için düzenliyoruz
         DoCmd.OpenReport "MusteriRaporu", acViewReport, "", "[Forms]![MusteriFormu]![Ad]=[Musteriler]![Ad]", acNormal

        'Raporu pdf file olarak disa aktariyoruz
        todaydate = Format(Date, "DDMMYYYY")
        fileName = Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\MusteriRaporu_" & todaydate & ".pdf"
        DoCmd.OutputTo acReport, "MusteriRaporu", acFormatPDF, fileName, False

        Set oemail = oApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        With oemail
            .To = rs.Fields("Email")
            .Subject = Me.Firma_Adi & " Bakiye Raporu"
            .Body = "Bakiye raporunuz ektedir."
            .Attachments.Add fileName

            If Not .To <> Me.Email Then
                .Send
                MsgBox "Email Gonderildi"
            Else
                MsgBox "Mail adresi hatali!"
            End If
        End With

        DoCmd.Close acReport, "MusteriRaporu", acSavePrompt
        rs.MoveNext
    Next idx

Leave:
    On Error Resume Next
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

ErrProc:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Leave
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) However when you removed the : Dodmc.Gotorecord acNext, you changed all project. As it can be seen my report collects its data with form condition. Also email send condition is corrected with me.Email which was on form. When i do my project like your code i cannot get customer based report. I already tried that and couldnt figured out that way :)

Comment: Man i love you <3 you made me understand what i was doing wrong. I had to close report at the end of loop. my code is working well now. :)